# Query All Posts: Either Display Most Recent or One with Particular ACF Value Chosen

Tags: wp-query, loop

I am using WP Query for a custom taxonomy–"featured layout"–and have two scenarios I'm trying to work out: either display the most recent Featured Layout that has a particular value set using Advanced Custom Fields OR display the most recent Featured Layout post (i.e. `$stickyToggle == yes`. The former would take precedence.

Right now, the following code only outputs the most recent post but I can't figure how to *first* check and output the post if it's *both* a Featured Layout and $stickyToggle = yes, and if it's not, just output the most recent Featured Layout. Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    //Getting 'Featured' Value
    $featured_value_cat_query = new WP_Query( array (
      'post_type' => 'seacoast_values',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'seacoast_value_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            //$term_slug is main category/taxonomy term
            'terms'    => $term_slug,
          ),
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'seacoast_value_layout_position',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'featured-layout',
            'orderby'  => 'date',
            'order'    => 'DESC',
          ),
      ),
    ) );

    $stickyToggle = get_field('seacoast_value_sticky_value');

    //Returning 'Featured'

    if ( $featured_value_cat_query->have_posts() ) {

      while ( $featured_value_cat_query->have_posts() ): $featured_value_cat_query->the_post(); ?>

    Post Content would be here

  <?php

    endwhile;  //end of 'Featured' loop

    //* Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

  } //end of if post ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run through the loop once and break when the sticky post is found. If it's not found, rewind the query and output the first found result:

```
<?php if ( $featured_value_cat_query->have_posts() ) {
   $count = 0;

   while ( $featured_value_cat_query->have_posts() ): 
      $featured_value_cat_query->the_post();

      if ( 'yes' == get_field('seacoast_value_sticky_value') )
      { 
         $count = 1; ?>

         // Post Content would be here

         <?php break;
      }

   endwhile;  //end of 'Featured' loop

   if ($count == 0) {
      $featured_value_cat_query->rewind_posts();

      while ( $featured_value_cat_query->have_posts() ): 
         $featured_value_cat_query->the_post(); ?>

         // Post Content would be here

         <?php break;

      endwhile;  //end of 'Featured' loop
   }
} //end of if post

//* Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```